# How to send multiple requests in one curl open connection

Tags: php, curl

i have an array with approximately 45 k usernames in in i want to hit a url using curl that would give me a response pertaining to those usernames.The issue is i want to achieve it in less time.

```
$username=['123','456','789'....] //upto 45k entries
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($username);$i++)
{
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://abc.com.pk/hxc/get_user_details.php?uname='.$username[$i]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
}
```

The above code depicts what i am doing right now but as usernames are in large numbers it takes alot of time to return all the responses.Is there any way i can achieve it in less time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curl-multi-init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) and [curl-multi-exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php) so that your requests are processed asynchronously.

Comment: is there a way to achieve it using  curl keep alive

Comment: I think the main issue is that you need to wait for one request to complete before moving to the next one, so no. Keep alive might improve performance by a little, but not significant enough.

Comment: i have read alot of examples about curl-multi-init they are all hitting different urls but i want to hit only one url again and again

Comment: Well, essentially, you are also hitting a "different" URL every time since the username is changing...

Comment: yea that was a dumb reason from my end but i am somehow unable to understand the process as what changes do i need to make in my code.Do i have to curl_init separately for each request

Comment: Yes. I think these 2 examples make more sense that the one on the official documentation: https://www.phpied.com/simultaneuos-http-requests-in-php-with-curl/ & http://arguments.callee.info/2010/02/21/multiple-curl-requests-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class , it speeds up our curl requests a lot.

It has multi-curl support enabled and it's very easy to use.

As for your question on the time, you can set the time out using

```
Curl::setTimeout($seconds)
```

Or in the case of MultiCurl

```
MultiCurl::setTimeout($seconds)
```

You can extend the timeout as much time as needed.